# how to verify if java sends the client certificate in a mutual auth scenario

Tags: ssl, cxf, apache-camel

I setup 2way ssl with Camel and CXF using the http conduit element etc.
I make a webservice call to an external party. All certificates are correctly installed (incoming traffic is succesfull, this is configured in Tomcat). After [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680416/apache-cxf-exception-in-ssl-communication-sockettimeout) post about secure renegotiation I finally received a response from the other party: HTTP response 403, forbidden.

I've been debugging with javax.net.debug=all and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) excellent explanation.
I can see in the logging that a secure connection is succesfully setup:

```
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 141, 25, 184, 254, 93, 9, 10, 48, 135, 161, 213, 57 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-2, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
```

and no other errors or warnings. How can I verify if my client certificate is sent to the server? (I can't use Wireshark but I have the javax.net.debug logging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666052/java-https-client-certificate-authentication) post and by comparing the javax.net.debug output to the [client auth example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake).
I don't see **CertificateVerify** in my log, only [the one way ssl steps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Simple_TLS_handshake), so there is no client certificate sent.

The cause was that I copied the CXF http conduit example from their website, but somehow the ciphersuite filter it contained was too strict.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to track this down and found the following.

In Java 11, I enabled SSL logging by adding this option to the tomcat server process I was using:
`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose:keymanager`.

Next, I ran my test and studied the logs.  The general format of all messages begin like this (so I won't repeat this because it clutters up the important content).

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|22|http-bio-8443-exec-1|2023-02-06 18:01:35.705 GMT|CertificateMessage.java:366|Produced ClientHello handshake message
```

### Client Side Logs: Successful mutual authentication

The following shows the SSL handshake messages that occurred during a successful two way certificate authentication.

```
Produced ClientHello handshake message
Consuming ServerHello handshake message
Consuming server Certificate handshake message  <<< Receiving Server cert
Consuming ECDH ServerKeyExchange handshake message
Consuming CertificateRequest handshake message <<< Server asking for client cert
Consuming ServerHelloDone handshake message
Produced client Certificate handshake message  <<< Sending client cert
Produced ECDHE ClientKeyExchange handshake message
Produced CertificateVerify handshake message
Produced ChangeCipherSpec message
Produced client Finished handshake message
Consuming ChangeCipherSpec message
Consuming server Finished handshake message
```

I highlighted the lines that show the server cert being received and the client cert being sent.  I should note that the above is the logs as viewed on the client side of the connect.

The SSL Spec (See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.6) says:

> This [the Client Certificate message] is the first message the client can send after receiving a
> ServerHelloDone message.  This message is only sent if the server
> requests a certificate

And once the `ClientKeyExchange` message is sent, we know that no client certificate was sent because again the spec says:

> This message is always sent by the client.  It MUST immediately
> follow the client certificate message, if it is sent.  Otherwise,
> it MUST be the first message sent by the client after it receives
> the ServerHelloDone message.

Since the `ServerHelloDone` message was printed, and then the `ClientKeyExchange` message was printed, therefore the `ClientCertificate` message **was not sent** because if it were being sent it needed to be sent immediately after the `SeverHelloDone` and before the `ClientKeyExchange`.

*This test was performed using Java 11.  I don't have the web libraries handy but this was not a SpringBoot application.*

### Server Side Logs: Successful mutual authentication with certs

For completeness, the following shows the messages that are logged by the server side of the two way authentication using certificates.

```
Consuming ClientHello handshake message
Ignore unavailable extension: supported_versions
Produced ServerHello handshake message
Produced server Certificate handshake message <<< Sending server cert
Produced ECDH ServerKeyExchange handshake message
Produced CertificateRequest handshake message <<< Request client send cert
Produced ServerHelloDone handshake message
Consuming client Certificate handshake message << Receiving clients cert
Consuming ECDHE ClientKeyExchange handshake message
Consuming CertificateVerify handshake message 
Consuming ChangeCipherSpec message
Consuming client Finished handshake message
Produced ChangeCipherSpec message
Produced server Finished handshake message
```

### Summary

This answer highlights the messages logged for the two way (aka mutual) authentication using X.509 certificates in a Java web application that both received incoming requests (and required mutual authentication) and making a REST call to another server that also required two way authentication.

Some of the log messages shown contain a large amount of additional information such as the actual certificate information and detailed values from the SSL specification.  None of that data is shown because it makes it harder to see the important messages  and it is not needed to understand the answer.

If you needed to see exactly what was sent in a certificate then the detailed logs provide that information.

Later, I tried this with a SpringBoot application using `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.7.3` and it also worked when running with

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose:keymanager"
```